# How do I find prime numbers in a dynamic array

Tags: c#

There are other questions on this topic but none of them really answer my question. I designed a piece of code to find the prime numbers in a dynamically sized array. Here is the code:

```
        int userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] grades = new int[userInput];
        for( int i = 2; i < grades.Length; i++ )
        {
            grades[i] = i;
            int[] prevNums = new int[i];
            List<int> primes = new List<int>();
            for (int k = 1; k < grades[i]; k++)
            {
                prevNums[k] = k;
                int result = grades[i] / k;

                bool failed = false;
                foreach (int n in prevNums) // go over every number in the list
                {
                    if (n == result) // check if it matches
                    {
                        failed = true;
                    }
                }
                if (failed == false && prevNums[k] == grades[i] - 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(grades[i]);
                    primes.Add(grades[i]);
                }
                
            }
            
        }
```

Instead of printing every prime in the array it instead always returns 2. Any suggestions would be super helpful. I do understand there is a very simple method to find primes but this is more of a test/educational thing than a piece of code to do a job.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code and logic. First - there is very fast formula for finding primes (keep this in mind). Second, your current logic has flaws. You don't need the whole part with `if (failed == false && prevNum..` what you need is to search all the numbers smaller than your current one (actually smaller than % 2) and if there is a match print it and break.

Comment: There really are too many flaws to get into. I think it would print out more things depending on your input, but it won't be what you expect.

Comment: I'd be better able to understand your code if the variable names were more logical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of printing every prime in the array it instead always returns 2

The reason for this is here

> `if (failed == false && prevNums[k] == grades[i] - 1)`

We can see that the **only** time you consider a number to be prime is if that number contains no number before it which is equal to `i/k` **and** if `k == (i - 1)`. One of the very few times this is true is for the number 2.

In order to talk about how to fix this we need to define what a prime number is and how to find it, and then compare that with your code. Doing that we can identify where we went wrong and how to fix it.

A number is considered prime if it's only divisible by 1 and itself. Knowing this we can create some simple instructions and create an algorithm from those instructions.

How can we check to see if a number is divisible by another number? In C# and most modern languages we can use the `%` modulo operator. This operator provides us with the remainder when two numbers are divided. So for 3/2 the remainder would be 1. But when we do say 2/1 we get 0 since 2 can be divided by 1 with no numbers left over.

In your code you identified if a number is divisible by using

> `grades[i] / k;`

This doesn't give us a remainder but we can easily change it to do so by replacing the division operator with the modulo operator(`%`).

Now that we can determine if a number is divisible by another number we need to find out if a number is prime.

To do that we look at all the numbers before the number we think is prime. When we look at the numbers we're checking to see if any number before the current number can be equally divided into the current number. If the remainder of dividing the two numbers is *not* zero, then the two numbers are *not* divisible. If the remainder is zero then they are equally divisible and the current number isnt prime.

Let's compare that with what you have, your code says "for each number between 2 and the input number(currentNumber), check if any number between 1 and the current number(previousNumber) are equal to the current number divided by the previous number. And if that is true then the current number is not prime".

I went ahead and created a working example of finding primes for what I think was the way you were intending. There are better ways such as the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), but I kept the code as similar to yours as possible.

```cs
// get the number from the user
int userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// create a place to put the primes we find
List<int> primes = new List<int>();

// count from 2(the smallest positive prime) and count torwards the user number
for (int i = 2; i < userInput; i++)
{
    // create a way to tell if the current number was divisible by some other number preceding it
    bool failed = false;

    // walk backwards from the current number and check each one
    for (int k = i; k-- > 2;)
    {
        // check to see if the current number / previous number has a remainder
        if (i % k == 0)
        {
            // since there was no remainder give up as the current number cant be prime
            failed = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if we got here and haven't failed
    // it means the number is prime and we should add it to the list
    if (failed == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        primes.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: A programming 101 student probably wouldn't use a construct like `k-- > 2` or even be able to explain it. If you're going to do someone's homework for them, perhaps consider carefully the level you're pitching at

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Although I believe an argument could be made for leaving it as it may offer another learning opportunity for OP as he may not recognize the expression and research it and along the way learn more about the syntax of C# and the vast option the language has available to him. Other than that, his question was well written, included an albeit faulty implementation and included what results he was getting and what should have been expected. I'm happy to help users who at the least attempted to help themselves.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment, it's just that in situations where there is a risk that someone will just take well presented, commented code and hand it in as their own I prefer not to provide it, but instead a set of nudges that get them to do the work and realize the goal. Also, not really sure what it offers over putting the decrement in the third operation of the `for`; it just seems like a readability/understandability sacrifice, especially as the loop *does* run for 2 despite initially looking like it doesn't. It's poor *glanceability* because you have to stop and think "wait.. what?"

Comment: I can also completely agree with yours as well. Unfortunately that is always a risk on SO and GitHub, all we can hope is that the people that come across our answers use them as intended. As for the decrement operator I believe the only non syntactic different is a single Jmp that is avoided when the loop statement is resolved  backwards at runtime. It is unlikely the compiler doesn't make this adjustment automatically however. When you boil that down an argument could be made about the readability, however, I would argue that its personal or company code style preference.

Comment: Does my profile say I am a programming 101 student. I need to fix that. I am a novice. I would not hand this in as homework as I do not take any programming classes, but I appreciate your worries.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your step by step process was very helpful not just for getting my code working but also understanding why.